# "Track the next one" no longer offers non-tag badges as options

Tags: bug, badges

After being awarded the same silver badge that I had been tracking, I clicked "Track the next one".

I was expecting to see options such as "Archaeologist" and "Enthusiast". Instead, all of the badges I was given to choose from were tag badges. This was the case regardless of whether I selected "Available", "All", "Gold", "Silver" or "Bronze".

I was able to work around this by pressing the "Let us pick" (or was it "Let us choose?") button, then trying to change the badge being tracked manually. This time I was offered the full set of badges to track, and chose "Archaeologist".

Comment: Thank you very much! You give me the answer. **Note for SO maintainers:** this is completely at the opposite of a clear UI/UX!